# Density of integers represented by norm form (cyclotomic field)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions, cyclotomic-fields, norm-forms

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ be the $n$th cyclotomic field, and $N$ be the [norm form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_form) constructed from the field norm of $K$. An interesting problem would be  the number of integers $l$ less than $x$ that can be represented by the norm form $N$ (in other words, there is an integral element of $K$, $f$, such that the field norm of $f$ is $l$) (assuming x is finite).

(I) More specifically to this problem, let $n$ be a prime and $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ as above. Let $L(x)$ represent the number of integers less than $x$ which can be represented by the norm form $N$ also defined above. What is a good upper and lower bound for $L(2^n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

My conjecture (II) $2^{(n-1)/2}<L(2^n)<2^{(3n-3)/4}$

Is anyone able to provide a better and more accurate lower bound than II for $L(2^n)$ to answer (I)?

For instance, when $n=7$, $L(2^7)=11$ because 11 integers less than or equal to $2^7$ are represented by $N: (1, 7, 8, 29, 43, 49, 56, 64, 71, 113, 127)$. It seems to fit my conjectured bound II as $2^3 < L(2^7) < 2^{4.5}$, $8 < 11 < 22.6$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you can use the prime number theorem for Hecke L-functions of characters of the ideal class group to obtain an asymptotic for $L(x)$. With $\nu(I) = 1$ if $I$ is a product of prime ideals of distinct norms, with $r(I) = \#\{ J, N(J) = N(I)\}$ then $\sum_I \frac{\nu(I)\psi(I)}{r(I)} N(I)^{-s}$ has an Euler product, which is close to $L(s,\psi)^{1/\varphi(n)}$, and summing over $\psi$ yields the Dirichlet series counting the integers being the norm of a principal ideal which is a product of prime ideals of distinct norms.

Comment: @reuns I remember learning this a couple years ago, would you mind giving me an example of this if you can? Thanks much appreciated.